Dynamically add MenuFlyoutElement to contect menu in .NET 8 Maui
I am trying to learn Maui by creating a small application.  Part of the application will be getting available comm ports and updating the context menu for selection.  For now, I am only trying to add a string to an element and then add the element to the list.
Here is the xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="EgretHUDCompanion.MainPage">

<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Count"
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Edit">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Count"
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Serial">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Refresh Comm Ports" Clicked="RefreshCommPorts"/>
        <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Select Port" x:Name="AvailablePortsList">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Comm 123"/>
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Task">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Get Comm Ports"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Connect"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Disconnect"/>
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Padding="30,0"
        Spacing="25">
        
        <Image
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            HeightRequest="185"
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

        <Label
            Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
            Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

        <Button
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me" 
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

Here is the method that should be updating the menu list named AvailablePortsList:
        private void RefreshCommPorts(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ee = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        ee.Text = $"Comm {count}";
        AvailablePortsList.Add(ee);
        //AvailablePortsList.Insert(0, ee);
    }

Each time this method runs, AvaillablePortsList has an additional element, but the UI does not update.
I assume I am missing some sort of UI update call?
Any help would be appreciated.

I found a similar link on github and I had the same issue when I was testing.
